# Loading a jQuery plugin using RequireJs

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I'm using require-jquery.js and I'm trying to load the [jsscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) plugin in my application.

I have this configuration in my index.html page (It's a single page application):

```
require( { paths: {
            'ca': 'cafe/ca',
            'casp': 'sp/sp',
            'ko': 'cafe/lib/knockout/knockout',
            'komap': 'cafe/lib/knockout/knockout.mapping',
            'kopost': 'cafe/lib/knockout/knockout-postbox',
            'jd': 'cafe/lib/jaydata/jaydata',
            'jdKo': 'cafe/lib/jaydata/jaydatamodules/knockout',
            'jdDeferred': 'cafe/lib/jaydata/jaydatamodules/deferred',
            'jqscroll': 'cafe/lib/jsscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min'
        },
        waitSeconds: 60,
        shim: {
            'jd': { exports: '$data', deps: [ 'cafe/lib/jaydata/datajs-1.0.3' ] },
            'jdDeferred': { exports: '$data', deps: [ 'jd' ] },
            'jqscroll': ['jquery']
        }
         ..............
```

Then i try to call the plugin from a module:

```
define( [ 'jquery', 'ko','jqscroll' ], function( $, ko ,jqscroll) {
     console.log(jqscroll);
}
```

But I keep getting undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: require(["jquery", "jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta"], function($) {
    //the jquery.alpha.js and jquery.beta.js plugins have been loaded.
    $(function() {
        $('body').alpha().beta();
    });
});

Comment: Oh, how stupid of me, it's been  along long day :), plesae post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Jaydata does not support requirejs yet but it is on our roadmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this helps.

```
require(["jquery", "jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta"], function($) {
    //the jquery.alpha.js and jquery.beta.js plugins have been loaded.
    $(function() {
        $('body').alpha().beta();
    });
});
```